# Typescript/Angular comma or dot in decimals using pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, decimal

I created my own custom pipe and I want to add a , or a . to thousands value for example : 1000 to be converted to 1,000 or 1.000

this is my custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'decimalUnitPipe'
})

export class DecimalUnitPipe implements PipeTransform {

    public transform(value: any) {

    }
}
```

Any ideea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to convert your value to thousands notation. This is how your `transform` function should be:

> ```
> public transform(value: any) {
>     return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");;
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you explain to me what this line does? :replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")

Comment: its a regular expression to insert a `,` after every 3 digits in your `value`

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question. If I have a number for example 1000 and I want to add after the comma 35 the number would be 1.000,35 or 1,000.35 How can I do that ?

Comment: if you write `{{ '1000,35' | decimalUnitPipe }}` then it will return `1,000,35`

Comment: I need this pipe to be applied on an input on an app I am working at. So there are times where you have like : $1.000,35 and the 35 represents (cents) or $1,000.35

Comment: give an example of your input value and what you want it to be converted into

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/48nKb like in this example I want to make it in a select and the user can select the input format he wants and this saves in the database

Comment: Look in the Positive input box in that picture I showed you , please

Comment: I think I need to parse a string to float with parsefloat

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to this so everything is kinda messed up

Comment: Here is a sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/KSWPYD3mhJgmdYJfwgH5?p=preview (this needs some improvement but the basic idea is same. Please also accept the answer if it helped)

Comment: Hey I created my own example. I have some bugs though. In the decimals if I select to show only 3 decimals and I put in the number just 2 it adds a 0 after the last one for example: 100.23 and I select to show 3 decimals it adds a 0 after like this : 100.230. And one more thing if I select to show 2 decimals and I put 3 like this : 100.126 it doesn't show 12 it rounds up to 13 so instead of showing 12 it shows 13. Here is my code:

Comment: public transform(value: any) {
        value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(parseInt(this.session.Settings.decimalDigits));
        console.log(value);
        var splitValue = value.toString().split(this.session.Settings.decimalSymbols)
        console.log(splitValue);
        var splitA = splitValue[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, this.session.Settings.groupSymbols);
        console.log(splitA);
        return splitA + this.session.Settings.decimalSymbols + splitValue[1];
    }
}